# Does the Big Spender VIP always buy up the cheapest of the 3 goods first?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

It's frustrating to see the Big Spender only spending less than 1000 at my store my my most expensive good is fully stocked which would net me 70k.

This happens when my VIP lounge is at full capacity and I accidentally clicked on the VIP button so I can't do any adjustments beforehand and have to depend on blind luck to send my VIP to the right store.

So the question is: does the Big Spender VIP always buy up the cheapest good 1st or it's totally random?

Comment: Moral of the story, don't send your Big Spenders to levels with multiple tiers of stock. Either wait until your best level has lots of level 3 and nothing else, or spend the bux to push it towards that state. Spending 6 bux to make $60,000 is a good trade, especially since bux-granting events seem to be a lot more frequent than previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be random.  I've definitely had them buy any of the three levels.

Answer (score 2):

It does appear to be random, but heavily skewed to getting the cheapest one. Most of the time, I time it, but of the 10 times which I did not, 9 of them turned out to be the cheapest payout.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be random for me,
just make sure you only have the third item fully stocked when you use him (when the othe 2 items have sold out)

Comment: This does work. I've used it myself.